# how to write mysql query with join and conditional sum with 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 mysql tables which saves invoice, invoice content and payment

- `inv_head(invno,invtot,invgtot)`
- `inv_body(invno,typeid,qty,rate,linetot)`
- `payment(invno,pay_amount,pay_method)`

```
select inv_head.invno,inv_head.invgtot,
sum(CASE WHEN payment.pay_method='CASH'  THEN payment.pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS pay_cash,
sum(CASE WHEN payment.pay_method='CHEQUE'  THEN payment.pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS pay_chq
from inv_head left JOIN payment on inv_head.invno=payment.invno   
where invdate between '2019-07-21 00:00:00' and '2019-07-21 23:00:00'  
and  unprodid=0
GROUP by inv_head.invno
```

returns below which is correct

```
invno           invgtot pay_cash    pay_chq 
20190721-173208-9   242.5   100     100 
20190721-174752-9   52  20      10
```

```
select inv_head.invno,inv_head.invtot,inv_head.invgtot,
sum(CASE WHEN inv_body.typeid=1  THEN inv_body.line_tot ELSE 0 END) AS stdsaletot,
sum(CASE WHEN inv_body.typeid=2  THEN inv_body.line_tot ELSE 0 END) AS rettot,
sum(CASE WHEN inv_body.typeid=3  THEN inv_body.line_tot ELSE 0 END) AS dmgtot,
sum(CASE WHEN inv_body.typeid=4  THEN (inv_body.qty * inv_body.rate)ELSE 0 END) AS fitot
from inv_head,inv_body  
where invdate between '2019-07-21 00:00:00' and '2019-07-21 23:00:00'  
and  unprodid=0 and inv_head.invno=inv_body.invno 
GROUP by inv_head.invno
```

returns below which is correct

```
invno           invtot  invgtot stdsaletot  rettot  dmgtot  fitot   
20190721-173208-9   242.5   242.5   242.5       0   0   0   
20190721-174752-9   52  52  291     -168    -71 0
```

but when i combine above 2 queries,

```
select inv_head.invno,inv_head.invtot,inv_head.invgtot,
sum(CASE WHEN payment.pay_method='CASH'  THEN payment.pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS pay_cash,
sum(CASE WHEN payment.pay_method='CHEQUE'  THEN payment.pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS pay_chq,
sum(CASE WHEN inv_body.typeid=1  THEN inv_body.line_tot ELSE 0 END) AS stdsaletot,
sum(CASE WHEN inv_body.typeid=2  THEN inv_body.line_tot ELSE 0 END) AS rettot,
sum(CASE WHEN inv_body.typeid=3  THEN inv_body.line_tot ELSE 0 END) AS dmgtot,
sum(CASE WHEN inv_body.typeid=4  THEN (inv_body.qty * inv_body.rate)ELSE 0 END) AS fitot
from inv_body,inv_head left JOIN payment on inv_head.invno=payment.invno  
where invdate between '2019-07-21 00:00:00' and '2019-07-21 23:00:00'  
and  unprodid=0 and inv_head.invno=inv_body.invno 
GROUP by inv_head.invno
```

returns below result which is erroneous

```
invno           invtot  invgtot pay_cash    pay_chq stdsaletot  rettot  dmgtot  fitot   
20190721-173208-9   242.5   242.5   100     100 727.5       0   0   0   
20190721-174752-9   52  52  80      40  873     -504    -213    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your join works properly on payment and inv_head but it is not working on inv_body because you did not provided how to join inv_body with other tables
Try this hope will help you

```
SELECT inv_head.invno,inv_head.invtot,inv_head.invgtot, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment.pay_method='CASH' THEN payment.pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS pay_cash, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment.pay_method='CHEQUE' THEN payment.pay_amount ELSE 0 END) AS pay_chq, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN inv_body.typeid=1 THEN inv_body.line_tot ELSE 0 END) AS stdsaletot, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN inv_body.typeid=2 THEN inv_body.line_tot ELSE 0 END) AS rettot, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN inv_body.typeid=3 THEN inv_body.line_tot ELSE 0 END) AS dmgtot,
       SUM(CASE WHEN inv_body.typeid=4 THEN (inv_body.qty * inv_body.rate)ELSE 0 END) AS fitot 
       FROM  payment RIGHT JOIN inv_head ON inv_head.invno=payment.invno
       WHERE invdate BETWEEN '2019-07-21 00:00:00' AND '2019-07-21 23:00:00'
         AND unprodid=0 LEFT JOIN inv_body ON inv_head.invno=inv_body.invno 
       GROUP BY inv_head.invno
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it give an error..guess we cannot place 'left join' under 'where' clause

Comment: Yes u need to use ON